# Separate and show priority items on top of a ListView? (Pinned Item functionality)

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

How to add the 'pinned item' functionality, similar to Google Keep, on a ListView?

I tried doing 2 list view, and putting the pinned one on top of a Column. But the problem is they scrolled separately, and if I wrapped the column in a Singlechildscrollview, it just gives error.

Am I on the right track of doing it or there is a way by just using a single list view?

Answer (score 0):

Implement if you want:

- add an extra field to your object: bool pinned -> then you sort the list to make sure the pinned items are on top of the list
- put a GestureDetector around the item and use the onTap to set the `pinned` value -> pinned = !pinned

Or try this package I just found:

https://pub.dev/packages/pinnable_listview

Comment: Sorting the data is fine, but I still need to put a separator between the pinned and unpinned, like a divider or text or something. Similar to Google Keep, it has a 'others' label for the normal notes, and 'pinned' label on the pinned one

Comment: You could add a dummy object to the list after all the pinned. You remember that index, and when the ListView.builder index == that index, you create divider instead of a ListTile/Text/Whatever you use? So the list would be: [pinned, pinned, dummy, normal, normal, normal] and when you are at dummy (index == 2), you return a Container(color: Colors.black, width: 100, height: 5)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the Singlechildscrollview worked the way I want it to. I just have to set the ListView `shrinkWrap: true`, and `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`. I'm not sure if this is a good idea tho, since most people say that shrinkWrap is quite a heavy operation to use.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text('Pinned'),
                PinnedListItemHere(), //ListView of Pinned Items
                Divider(
                  height: 25.0,
                  thickness: 2.0,
                ),
                Text('Others'),
                UnpinnedListItemHere(), //ListView of Unpinned Items
              ],
            ),
          ),
```